# I would like to consult a list of Twitter feeds, select the tweet with most retweets, then post it to Telegram. Is this possible?

Tags: twitter, zapier

I'd like the Zap to run every day, which I've found with schedule.

But when I look at the Twitter options, I only have "actions", but can't read the data and chose a tweet based on some criteria. Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Each zap can only have one trigger. It sounds like you set up a zap with a schedule trigger (so it happens once a day), which means you can't use a twitter trigger also (just action, like you're seeing).

We've got a `New Search Mention` that will trigger when there's a new tweet matching a user or search term (you don't want every tweet). You'll be able to get like/retweet info from that, and then act (or filter) on it based on that. You could use [Storage](https://zapier.com/help/storage/) and a code step to track the max all all tweets, and then (in a second tweet) once a day send whatever the max is to telegram (and reset the counter).

The biggest issue about that right now is since the trigger fires very quickly after the tweet is created, the engagement info will pretty close to 0. What you'd need is a way to look up tweet info as a search, so you could do:

1. New Search Mention
2. Delay
3. Fetch tweet info (<-- only part that's not currently possible)
4. code step (check max RTs, set it to this tweet if it's higher)

There are some other corner cases concerning the reset (when do you stop counting tweets? an hour before post?; tweets from early in the day have more hours to get retweeted, placing them at an advantage; etc), but you could make some calls.

So, **tl;dr**: not possible right now, but I can certainly put in a request for the `Get Tweet Info` action, which is most of what you need.

How does that sound?

Comment: Wow thank you, this was a very clear explanation of what can and cannot be done. The "get tweet info" would be great !

Comment: Cool! If you write into support@zapier.com they can log the request with your email so you're notified if/when it happens (reference this question and they can ping me or make a more detailed feature request). Otherwise I can log it and you could keep an eye (or make a zap) on the [updates blog](https://zapier.com/apps/updates).